# Reset Loading Bar

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a side project which is a Web Browser and I seem to be stuck.

I have a loading bar at the bottom left corner of the web browser and it fully functional except it doesn't reset the green loading bar (it fills up the bar with a green color while navigating but doesn't reset after).

In case I would run into some weird situation where it would actually bug for some reason, I've had some weird bugs lately I'm trying to exclude them.

I am looking for advice and tips on what I could try.

Here is the source code:

```
namespace WeWolf_Browser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //This Function Will Terminate The Software From The MenuStrip (File > Exit)
        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        //This Function Will Make a Message Box Pop Up On The Users Screen With Information About The Software.
        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Simple Browser Created By Me");
        }


        //This Will Navigate the browser to the users input.
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigateToPage();
        }



        //This is the "Core "Function" "  That Will Navigate The URL With The Enter KeyChar
        private void NavigateToPage()
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Navigation Loading";
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }

        //This Action will allow people use use the KeyPress Enter to navigate to the desired URL.
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.Enter)

               {

                NavigateToPage();
            }
        }


        //This WIll Make The Progress Bar Load While The Browser Is Loading.
        private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CurrentProgress > 0 && e.MaximumProgress > 0)

            {
                toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Value = (int)(e.CurrentProgress * 100 / e.MaximumProgress);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripStatusLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Navigation Has Finished";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you expect it to return to `0`? Why are you excluding `0` by this code: `e.CurrentProgress > 0` (I guess the value you want)?

Comment: In case I would run into some weird situation where it would actually bug for some reason, I've had some weird bugs latley & im trying to exclude them asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Value = 0;` to `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I read you want to reset it to `0` if an error occurs. You need to use a `try ... catch` statement to act on errors.

On every event handler, put a `try ... catch` block and reset the progress bar:

```
try
{
    // your actual code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // show it to the user
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    // reset progress bar
    toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Value = 0;
}
```